# reshape() function to make wide to long data

Tags: r, reshape, long-format-data, wide-format-data

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(ID = 1:10,
                   weight_hus = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
                   weight_wife = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
                   height_hus = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
                   height_wife = rnorm(10, 0, 1))
```

I am trying to use reshape() function

(due to some reasons, I can not use tidyverse function or other packages' function.
wanna use reshape() function)

```
data2 <- reshape(data = data,
                 idvar = "ID",
                 seperator = "_",
                 direction = "long",
                 v.name = c("body"),
                 timevar = c("hus", wife)
               )
```

but it never works...

Comment: There are several errors in your code: (1) there is no argument `seperator`, use `sep = ` instead; (2) "wife" needs to be quoted; (3) you need to specify the `varying = ` argument. What should the final output look like? Please include any error messages when code fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(ID = 1:10,
                   weight_hus = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
                   weight_wife = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
                   height_hus = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
                   height_wife = rnorm(10, 0, 1))

data2 <- reshape(data = data,
                 idvar = "ID",
                 varying = list(c("weight_hus", "weight_wife"), c("height_hus", "height_wife")),
                 v.names = c("weight", "height"),
                 direction = "long",
                 times = c("hus", "wife"),
                 timevar = "gender"
               )
```

Changes made:

1. Replaced `seperator` with `varying` to specify the variables to be reshaped.
2. Used `v.names` to provide meaningful names for the reshaped variables.
3. Changed `timevar` to "gender" to represent the different groups ("hus" and "wife").

Comment: You could also have `reshape` guess the names - `reshape(data, idvar="ID", direction="long", varying=-1, sep="_", timevar="gender")` - though being explicit about the groupings can make it more error-proof.